# Editing text files in a directory with PHP

Tags: php

I've got a script which lists all the txt files that I have in a directory. I've put a hyperlink each of the results that comes up and I want to the redirect to a simple editor which I have the code for.

This is the code for listing the files in the directory;

```
<?php
//Open directory
$dir = dir("content");
//List files in directory
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
    //Make sure it's a .txt file
    if(strlen($file) < 5 || substr($file, -4) != '.txt')
        continue;

    echo "Page: <a href='content/" .$file. "'>" . $file . "</a><br />";
}

$dir->close();
?>
```

And the code to edit the file:

```
<?
if($_POST['Submit']){
    $open = fopen("content/body.txt","w+");
    $text = $_POST['update'];
    fwrite($open, $text);
    fclose($open);
    echo "File updated.<br />"; 
    echo "File:<br />";
    $file = file("content/body.txt");
    foreach($file as $text) {
        echo $text."<br />";
    }
}else{
    $file = file("content/body.txt");
    echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">";
    foreach($file as $text) {
        echo $text;
    } 
    echo "</textarea>";
    echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
    </form>";
}
?>
```

What's the best way to try and do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have? Where are you stuck? What is the specific question you are asking?

Comment: The problem isn't in the code, I just want to know if there is a way I can use the hyperlinks on the files in the directory list to then edit them with this editor script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

in directory list use this:

```
echo "Page: <a href='editor_script.php?filename=".$file."'>".$file."</a><br/>";
```

in your editor script use this:

```
$open = fopen("content/".$_GET['filename'].".txt","w+");

$file = file("content/".$_GET['filename'].".txt");
```

I' not sure but maybe you have to remove `action` from `form`

```
echo '<form method="post">';
```

or use url with `$_GET['filename']`

```
echo '<form action="editor_script.php?filename='.$_GET['filename'].'" method="post">';
```

maybe this works too but I'm not sure

```
echo '<form action="?filename='.$_GET['filename'].'" method="post">';
```